# Linq select returned where clause field

Tags: sql, linq, dynamic

```
var AbbA = (from t1 in mdc.table1 
join t2 in mdc.table2 on t1.id equals t2.id
select new { t1, t2 }).AsQueryable();

if(a=1)
   AbbA=AbbA.Where(q=>q.t1.cid==x);
else
   AbbA=AbbA.Where(q=>q.t1.cid==y);

var Global=Abba.Select(q=> new{NewName1 = t1.field1, NewName2=t2.field2}).ToList();
```

I want to list only 2 fields. But returned 2 fields and where clause field.

Profiler view

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[cid] AS [cid], >>> This is where clause filed
    [Extent1].[field1] AS [NewName1], 
    [Extent2].[field2] AS [NewName2]
    FROM  [dbo].[table1] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[table2] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[id] = [Extent2].[id]
    WHERE [Extent1].[cid] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=10000
```

Comment: cid field have clustered (IX_INDEX) index. for that reason be?

Comment: this line here will add a where clause AbbA=AbbA.Where(q=>q.t1.cid==x);

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question...why did the generated sql include a where clause?

this line here will add a where clause because it is still forming the queryable expression tree

```
AbbA=AbbA.Where(q=>q.t1.cid==x);
```

If you want to remove your where clause from the generated sql then add a ToList() at the end of your query, you will then manipulate the results using linq to objects and you will be manipulating the actual objects in memory after they have been retrieved from sql.

```
var AbbA = (from t1 in mdc.table1 
join t2 in mdc.table2 on t1.id equals t2.id
select new { t1, t2 }).ToList();
```

Comment: Hello, @Twisted Inferno,
>>why did the generated sql include a where clause?
YES! cid field is index field. I tryed another filed for where clause it's not returned.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand what you're saying